# Incomplete copy from struct to array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, memcpy

I have defined:

```
 #define arrayLengthInStruct 50

 typedef struct {
  struct {
        int _buf[arrayLengthInStruct];           
        int _bufLen;
 } _context;
} _handle;
```

in main()

```
_handle handlePtr;
_handle* handle = (_handle*) &handlePtr;   // data is here
int* k_src = NULL; // to be loaded to
int i = 0;

handlePtr._context._bufLen = arrayLengthInStruct;
// initialize the source
for (i = 0; i < handlePtr._context._bufLen; i++) {
    handlePtr._context._buf[i] = i+1;
    printf("%d \t", handlePtr._context._buf[i]);
}
printf("\n");

k_src = malloc(sizeof(int)*(handlePtr._context._bufLen)); 
printf("Amount of data to copy: %d \n", handle->_context._bufLen);   


  memcpy ( k_src,
  &handle->_context._buf[0],
   handle->_context._bufLen
 );

for (i = 0; i < handlePtr._context._bufLen; i++) {
    printf("%d \t", k_src[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

However, the copy is incomplete. What am I missing?

output:
/*
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24      25      26
27      28      29      30      31      32      33      34      35      36      37      38      39
40      41      42      43      44      45      46      47      48      49      50

Amount of data to copy: 50

1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
*/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third argument to [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) is the number of **bytes** to copy. You provided the number of `int`s. Do this instead:

```
memcpy ( k_src,
&handle->_context._buf[0],
 handle->_context._bufLen * sizeof(int)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the fact that `memcpy` copies a number of *bytes* rather than integers. You need to multiply your array size by `sizeof(int)` when using it with `memcpy`.

On a little-endian machine with four-byte `int` type, copying 50 *bytes* would give you what you see (50 / 4 = 12.5) though the last element `13` would depend on what was already in the destination memory.